# How to prevent the X button on a form to save data

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Whenever I click the (X) button on my form, it still keeps the data. I want to be able to close the form using the (X) button and not save any data. Does anyone have an idea of why is this happening?

Scenario:

Form1 has a button [enter car information] 
when I click the button, another form opens, Form2, where I can type all the car information. Once I click OK button, Form2 closes and Form 1 gets updated with Form2s information.

My problem:

If I click the X button on Form2, Form1 still updates with Form2s information. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think I found a way to solve this. If I create a condition where I check that the OK button wasn't pressed or the cancel button wasn't either, then it means that the close (X) button was pressed. All I had to do was to put this condition before updating Form1.
`if (!Form2.closedCancel() && addressForm.closedOk()) //OK clicked
     updateForm1();
else
     don'tUPdate' // OK button,cancel button not clicked`

Answer (score 0):

It is the way AX is designed. Pressing 'Esc' key or 'Ctrl+Q' will quit without saving or ask you if you want to save your changes. But it will be only for the latests.